# Programmatically disable all Notification Center banners on Mac

Tags: objective-c, macos

Can a Mac app temporarily disable Notification Center, for example while it is doing a full-screen presentation? Apple says alerts are "automatically disabled while you’re presenting in Keynote. They also won’t appear if your display is mirrored on an external monitor." Do third-party apps also have the ability to temporary disable notifications?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, but my assumptions are base on iOS, where you can't turn off notification center at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable Focus (aka Do Not Disturb) which will hide current notifications and prevent new ones from popping up. See https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/turn-a-focus-on-or-off-mchl999b7c1a/mac for how to enable/disable it.

I do not know if applications themselves have control over enabling/disabling Focus.

I use the Touch Bar and add the Focus button to quickly enable it if I need to present or share screen. I do not see a keyboard shortcut you can set in Monterrey like you could in Big Sur.